# < > symbols in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a mysql dump and when i execute the file a 0 or a 1 appears before the < or > symbol, how can I use this symbol in a batch file?

`mysqldump -u root -p extractor --routines > E:\MySQLDumpCMD\newsql.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. `cmd` just outputs what is intended. In your case `<` redirects the standard input stream (0) and `>` redirects the standard output stream (1). Which is to say that `0<` is the same as `<` and `1>` is the same as `>`. So both ways of writing it are equivalent.